# How to organize all shapes for each color in rows of ggplot legend?

Tags: r, ggplot2

For a plot like this:

```
df <- structure(list(x = c(-0.951618567265016, -0.0450277248089203, 
-0.784904469457076, -1.66794193658814, -0.380226520287762, 0.918996609060766, 
-0.575346962608392, 0.607964322225033, -1.61788270828916, -0.0555619655245394
), y = c(0.519407203943462, 0.301153362166714, 0.105676194148943, 
-0.640706008305376, -0.849704346033582, -1.02412879060491, 0.117646597100126, 
-0.947474614184802, -0.490557443700668, -0.256092192198247), 
    color = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L
    ), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4"), class = "factor"), shape = structure(c(1L, 
    2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("1", "2", 
    "3"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
g <- ggplot() +
  geom_point(data = df, aes(x = x, y = y, colour = color, shape = shape)) +
  theme(legend.position = "right")
```

[image: observed]

Is it possible to somehow obtain the legend in the following format?

[image: desired]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this is what you are looking for.

1. The starting point is to have only one legend. To this end I add a new variable `shape_color` as the interaction of your factos `color` and `shape`.
2. Map `shape_color` on both `color` and `shape`.
3. To get the colors and shapes right we make use of `scale_xxx_manual`. To this end I set up two vectors with `colors` and `shapes`.
4. Organize the legend in rows using `guide_legend` with arguments `nrow = 4` and `byrow = TRUE`
5. The tricky part is the labelling.

   a. To this end I use a helper function which replaces the unwanted labels to empty strings, i.e. only every third label is shown, and makes sure that only the color category shows up in the label

   b. Finally, to have the label for the fourth row also on the right we have to make sure that the empty categories are "included" in the legend. To this end I use arguemnt `drop=FALSE` in both scales so that unused levels are included in the legend. However, I set the color and the shape for these categories to NA so that they are invisible.

```r
library(ggplot2)

df <- structure(list(x = c(-0.951618567265016, -0.0450277248089203, 
                           -0.784904469457076, -1.66794193658814, -0.380226520287762, 0.918996609060766, 
                           -0.575346962608392, 0.607964322225033, -1.61788270828916, -0.0555619655245394
), y = c(0.519407203943462, 0.301153362166714, 0.105676194148943, 
         -0.640706008305376, -0.849704346033582, -1.02412879060491, 0.117646597100126, 
         -0.947474614184802, -0.490557443700668, -0.256092192198247), 
color = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L
), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4"), class = "factor"), shape = structure(c(1L, 
                                                                          2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("1", "2", 
                                                                                                                          "3"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                        -10L))
df$shape_color = interaction(df$shape, df$color)

colors <- rep(scales::hue_pal()(4), each = 3)
shapes <- rep(scales::shape_pal()(3), 4)
colors <- setNames(colors, levels(df$shape_color))
shapes <- setNames(shapes, levels(df$shape_color))

colors[!levels(df$shape_color) %in% df$shape_color] <- NA
shapes[!levels(df$shape_color) %in% df$shape_color] <- NA

mylabels <- function(breaks) {
  breaks[!grepl("^3", breaks)] <- ""
  gsub("^\\d+\\.", "", breaks)
}

ggplot() +
  geom_point(data = df, aes(x = x, y = y, colour = shape_color, shape = shape_color)) +
  scale_color_manual(values = colors, labels = mylabels, drop = FALSE) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = shapes, labels = mylabels, drop = FALSE) +
  guides(color = guide_legend(nrow = 4, byrow = TRUE, label.position = "right")) +
  theme(legend.position = "right", legend.key = element_rect(fill = NA))
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent job Stefan. I don't think this approach would have occurred to me.

Comment: @AllanCameron Thanks Allan. However, from all the great work I have seen by you, I'm quite sure that you would have come up with a similar solution. (; Best S.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for this answer, it works really well although Im having trouble generalizing to my real data which is like 12 shapes and 34 colors lol. probably need to play around with this idea a bit more